# EditText array of existing EditTexts won't be declared right

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I am creating an app, in which I create some EditTexts dynamically with ID number.

I want to pass the information from the EditTexts, so I tried to create a EditText array with these and then use the .getText().toString() to save them in a String Array, which I want pass to the next activity.

It seems like it won't create the "editArray[]" in second code part correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code (EnterNames.java) - Creation of EditTexts -> Succesful

```
protected void NumberOfEditText()
{
    View VertLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.VertLayout);

    String SpinValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SpinValue");
    int intSpinValue = Integer.valueOf(SpinValue);

    editTextCount = intSpinValue;
    EditText[] editTextArray = new EditText[editTextCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < editTextCount; i++)
    {
        String Name = "Name " + (i+1);
        editTextArray[i] = new EditText(this);
        editTextArray[i].setId(i+1000);
        editTextArray[i].setText(Name);
        editTextArray[i].setTextSize(20);
        editTextArray[i].setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15) } );
        editTextArray[i].setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        editTextArray[i].setSingleLine(true);
        editTextArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((LinearLayout) VertLayout).addView(editTextArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Second code (EnterNames.java) - Passing data to next activity -> Failure.
By testing I think the problem is the for-loops (the editArray returns null)

```
public void Go(View view)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names);

    String NameArray [] = new String [editTextCount];
    EditText editArray [] = new EditText [editTextCount];

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomGeneration.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < editTextCount; i++)                 
    {                                                       
        editArray[i] = (EditText) findViewById(i+1000);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < editTextCount; i++)
    {
        NameArray[i] = editArray[i].getText().toString();
    }

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    extras.putInt("NumberofNames", editTextCount);
    extras.putStringArray("NameArray", NameArray);

    intent.putExtras(extras);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply declare `editTextArray` as a class variable, so you don't have to regenerate `editArray` in your `Go()` method?

Comment: Im dumb .. Good solution.
I have a fast question though:
How do I declare the size of this array after it is declared as class variable? (i recieve the value of the size from the past activity).

Comment: Simple: Just don't initialize your EditText[] when you declare it. I am going to make a complete answer, comment is too short to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `Activity.findViewById()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29), this method will search for views in your XML, not in views added in Java.

The simple way to do what you want:

```
class EnterNames extends Activity {
    private int editTextCount;
    private EditText[] editTextArray;

    protected void NumberOfEditText() {
        LinearLayout vertLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.VertLayout);

        editTextCount = Integer.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SpinValue"));
        editTextArray = new EditText[editTextCount];

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for (int i = 0; i < editTextCount; i++) {
            String Name = "Name " + (i+1);
            editTextArray[i] = new EditText(this);
            editTextArray[i].setText(Name);
            editTextArray[i].setTextSize(20);
            editTextArray[i].setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15) } );
            editTextArray[i].setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            editTextArray[i].setSingleLine(true);
            editTextArray[i].setLayoutParams(params);
            vertLayout.addView(editTextArray[i]);
        }
    }

    […]

    public void Go(View view)
    {
        // This will delete views added to your LinearLayout, don't use it!
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names);

        String nameArray[] = new String[editTextCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < editTextCount; i++) {
            nameArray[i] = editArray[i].getText().toString();
        }

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("NumberofNames", editTextCount);
        extras.putStringArray("NameArray", nameArray);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomGeneration.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I'm gonna go with this :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names); in public void Go(View view)? You overide Activities layout in which you previously has added EditText views and all your findById() returns null.

Your code should work if you remove setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names); from Go function.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_names); should be called single time in Activities onCreate function.